# Звернути в'язи, голову чи шию?

Tags: вживання-слів

Який виразів ("Звернути в'язи", "звернути голову" чи "звернути шию"?" доречно використовувати по відношенню до людини?
В мережі знайшла інформацію про те, що "звернути голову" стосується тварин. Що тоді з двома іншими варіантами?

Answer (score 5):

У [Словнику української мови в 11 т.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) не вказана якась різниця щодо використання цих виразів, що бачимо з прикладів вживання:

> ПОЗВЕРТА́ТИ, а́ю, а́єш, док.
>
> ◊ **Позверта́ти в’я́зи (ши́ї, го́лови)**: а) те саме, що **Зверну́ти в’я́зи (ши́ю, го́лову**) (всім або багатьом) (див. зверта́ти). Ще б десь дістати вишиту сорочку, і тоді хай хто заїкнеться, що Северин не козацького роду, так він і в’язи позвертає, щоб ішов уперед, а бачив назад (Тют., Вир, 1964, 422); б) (собі) те саме, що Зверну́ти в’я́зи (ши́ю, го́лову) (про всіх або багатьох) (див. зверта́ти). Гнат і жінка його були тепер похожі на ті верби, що виросли на степу при дорозі, що вітер як не зовсім зламає, то повикручує так, що вони ні на що не похожі, наче їх хто заставляв проти волі танцювати, аж покіль вони собі голів не позвертали (Григ., Вибр., 1959, 307).

Нерозрізнення цих виразів бачимо також у статті[ОБРАЗНИЙ ОБШИР ФРАЗЕОЛОГІЗМІВ
З КОМПОНЕНТОМ ГОЛОВА В УКРАЇНСЬКІЙ МОВНІЙ КАРТИНІ СВІТУ Клименко Ніна](http://philology.knu.ua/php/4/7/Studia_Linguistica_5_1/009_023.pdf):

> **звернути шию (в'язи, голову)**  –
>   1) сильно покалічити, побити кого-небудь або
>   2) убити кого-небудь

Тому, вважаю, що розрізняти ці вислови непотрібно.

(Для кращої відповіді уточніть де саме Ви знайшли інформацію про вживання "звернути голову").

Answer (score 1):

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvertaty) пише:

> **Звернути в'язи (шию, голову)**: (кому) *убити, скрутивши шию, різко завернувши голову* (звичайно ***птахові***).

Однак вже в іншій статті того ж [СУМу-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozvertaty/) пише:

> **ПОЗВЕРТАТИ**, аю, аєш, док. **3.** перех., розм. ***Ударивши, різко повернувши, перекосити, викривити, пошкодити щелепи, в'язи, кінцівки і т. ін.***
>
> ♦ **Позвертати в'язи (шиї, голови)**:
>
> Гнат і жінка його були тепер похожі на ті верби, що виросли на степу при дорозі, що вітер як не зовсім зламас, то повикручує так, що вони ні на що не похожі, наче їх хто заставляв проти волі танцювати, аж покіль вони собі голів не позвертали (Грицько Григоренко, Вибр., 1959, 307).

Отже, якщо *у прямому значенні "убити"*, то йдеться про тварин (птахів), якщо ж це *розмовне* у значенні *викривити*, то можна застосовувати і до *людей*.

Comment: Мені здається, «викривляти» воно позначає лише в конкретному прикладі про верби. А загалом і щодо людей — це все-таки радше «вбити / покалічити», як [каже інша відповідь](). Та й той приклад з вербами можна вважати частковим випадком значення «покалічити». (І головне — нема, власне, висновку — які саме з цих виразів можна застосовувати, чи всі, — бо, здається, саме це питав автор запитання.)